# How can I use gatsby-plugin-image in a map function?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am just starting with gatsby and having trouble figuring out how to use gatsby-plugin-image in the following case:

```
const array  = [
    {
        title: "Image 1",
        image: "../images/image1.jpg"
    },
    {
        title: "Image 2",
        image: "../images/image2.jpg"
    },
    {
        title: "Image 3",
        image: "../images/image3.jpg"
    },
    {
        title: "Image 4",
        image: "../images/image4.jpg"
    }
]

export default Section = function(){

    return (
        <div className="bg-white w-full">

                    {array.map((item, index) => (

                        <div key={index} className="flex flex-col items-center lg:items-start">

                               <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                               //How do I use the image plugin here?

                        </div>

                    ))}
        </div>
    )

}
```

What I tried and doesnt work:

```
{array.map((item, index) => (

    <div key={index} className="flex flex-col items-center lg:items-start">

           <h2>{item.title}</h2>
           <StaticImage src={item.image}/>

    </div>

))}
```

I know I am supposed to use GatsbyImage and GraphQl Query for this, but I cant figure out how. What I did now is this workaround:

```
import image1 from "../images/image1 .jpg"
import image2 from "../images/image2.jpg"
import image3 from "../images/image3.jpg"
import image4 from "../images/image4.jpg"

const array  = [
    {
        title: "Image 1",
        image: image1 
    },
    {
        title: "Image 2",
        image: image2
    },
    {
        title: "Image 3",
        image: image3 
    },
    {
        title: "Image 4",
        image: image4
    }
]

export default Section = function(){

    return (
        <div className="bg-white w-full">

                    {array.map((item, index) => (

                        <div key={index} className="flex flex-col items-center lg:items-start">

                               <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                               <img src={item.image} className="w-50 h-44 object-cover"></img>

                        </div>

                    ))}
        </div>
    )

}
```

But obviously with this I dont take advantage of gatsby image plugin, and its more tedious.

My Config:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss",
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
      __key: "images",
    },
  ],
};
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66911775/16038414), but this doesnt answer how I would iterate over specific images in my images folder and add additional info (title, description, alttext, etc.). It just shows how I would get 1 specific image as far as I understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your filesystem structure, I think your best chance is to use `GatsbyImage` component, as you said. Something like this should work:

```
{
  allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        childImageSharp {
          relativePath
          gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that [page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) are only available in the top-level components (pages), if you want to use it in a custom component (`Section`) you may need to drill down the props or using a [`StaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/).

When you set up the filesystem, the `name` attribute becomes the `sourceInstanceName` so you can create a custom GraphQL query to retrieve all images.

In your component then:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.allFile.edges.node.map((item, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>
          <GatsbyImage image={item.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt="" />
       </div>

       })}

    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
      allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED)
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
`

export default HomePage
```

Of course, tweak the snippet above to adapt it to your needs.

At this point, you can mix both arrays (`array` and the GraphQL data) to get the `title` if needed or you can customize the node to add your custom data.

---

Given a JSON (or an array) like:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "../../path/to/your/image.png"
      "title": "an image"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "../../path/to/your/image.png"
      "title": "an image"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "../../path/to/your/image.png"
      "title": "an image"
    },
  ]
}
```

Then, taking advantage of the same loop you can so something like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import JSONData from "../../content/My-JSON-Content.json"

const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.allFile.edges.node.map((item, index) => {
        if(JSONData.content.path.includes(item.relativePath)) {
          return <div key={index}>
            <h1>{JSONData.content.find(jsonElement=>jsonElement.path ==item.relativePath)}</h1>
            <GatsbyImage image={item.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt="" />
          </div>
        }
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Tweak it to adapt it to your needs.

References:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#gatsbyimage
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! It helps alot. You say I can add my custom data to the node. I cant find how to do it, how would I do that? It would be great if I could just attach the necessary data to the file itself, rather then join the data later.

Comment: The schema customization is extremely related to your data structure so it's difficult to guess how the code should looks like with sample data. Check https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/

Comment: The only data I have right now are the images in the images folder. So how could I add for example a title to every image node? Your link tells me I could maybe create a JSON file with every necessary data, but wouldnt I have to join them again aswell? Thanks for your help again btw!

Comment: Found this, which perfectly answers my question, it seems to have a downside of getting slow with many images, but I dont have that many, so its fine for now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508865/16038414 Thank you for your help you sent me in the right direction :)

Comment: I don't think it fits you since in the end, is using the same node as mine (`allFile`) you  can't add the `title` directly. The easiest solution given your use-case is to create a JSON or a markdown with the images paths and the titles. Then, using a query (depending on the chosen node it will be different) you can fetch that data using GraphQL and loop the object like I'm doing in with the `allFile`. If you found the article you can answer your own question or accept/upvote mine to close the issue. I was about to provide more details but it seems you have already managed to fixed it

Comment: I agree I went with the JSON method you proposed and it worked better. Didnt have to copy my array from file to file when reusing the images. I cant upvote yet, so I accepted your answer. Thanks again, you helped me alot!